# FileSystemWatcher and timer together

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, filesystemwatcher

I've read the suggested posts when writing the title of my question, but couldn't help much. The code looks like mine, but there's something i'm doing that may be wrong. Also i would like to add a few questions during this one hehe.

I'm writing a program that will run a `FileSystemWatcher` and a `Timer`, together.
When the user presses the start button, it will trigger the `Timer` and `FileSystemWatcher`.

As long `FileSystemWatcher` is monitoring the folder, the `Timer` is running.
If no file is received, nothing happens.
If a file is created, enqueue it inside the `OnCreated` event and restart the `Timer`.

After file(s) was(were) created and the timer expired, it starts the work on the `FileProcessor` class.

I saw many samples of `FileProcessor` class suited for specific needs and thats what i did with mine. Changed to attend my requisites.

So, instead of starting the job in the moment a job is enqueued, i wait until the `Timer` expires and then start to process.

Until now everything is going fine but here's what happens:
When the `FileProcessor` class is doing its work, the `FileSystemWatcher` stops monitoring the folder. No file is detected after the `FileProcessor` thread ends, timer restarts normally. I would like to ask help to see if there's anything wrong with that, if i should use another component rather than `FileSystemWatcher`.

Also, an question with this one: I want to detect files that are created while the program is working, and process them later. For this need i added an separate counter, to catch the original count of the queue before the loop starts dequeueing. Is this a good approach ?

Thanks in advance !

Form Code:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Telerik.WinControls;


namespace DI_Plot_2018
{
    public partial class RadForm1 : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
    {
        FileSystemWatcher InputFileWatcher;
        FileProcessor TIFFProcessor;
        static Timer timer1;
        bool RestartTimer;
        LoadInternalSettings InternalSettings;
        double CurrentCounter;        
        public RadForm1()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();
            RestartTimer = false;
            InternalSettings = new LoadInternalSettings();
            //counter = Int32.Parse(InternalSettings.Timer);
            timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(SecondElapsed);
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            TIFFProcessor = new FileProcessor();
            LoadControls(InternalSettings);
        }
        DateTime start;
        double s;

        private void CountDown()
        {
            start = DateTime.Now;
            s = Double.Parse(InternalSettings.Timer);            
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void SecondElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double remainingSeconds = s - (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds;            
            if(RestartTimer == true)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                CountDown();
                RestartTimer = false;
            }
            else if (remainingSeconds <= 0)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                if(TIFFProcessor.FilesQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    TIFFProcessor.FireProcessing(CurrentCounter);
                }                
                CountDown();
            }
            var x = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(remainingSeconds);
            CurrentCounter = x.Seconds;
            TimerTextBox.Text = x.Seconds.ToString();
        }
        private void FileCreated(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
            {
                TIFFProcessor.EnqueueJob(e.FullPath, CurrentCounter);
                RestartTimer = true;
            }
        }
        private void ButtonChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButton bt = sender as Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButton;
            string buttonName = (String)bt.Name;
            SwitchButtonImage buttonImageSwitch;
            switch (buttonName)
            {
                case "StartButton":
                    {
                        InputFileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(InputFolderTextBox.Text);
                        InputFileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileCreated);
                        InputFileWatcher.Filter = "*.tif";
                        InputFileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                        StopButton.Enabled = true;
                        StartButton.Enabled = false;
                        CountDown();
                        //TimerStart();
                        break;
                    }
                case "StopButton":
                    {
                        InputFileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                        timer1.Stop();
                        StopButton.Enabled = false;
                        StartButton.Enabled = true;
                        break;
                    }
                case "ImageRotationButton":
                    {
                        buttonImageSwitch = new SwitchButtonImage(ImageRotationButton, "ImageRotationIndex");
                        break;
                    }
                case "ImageOrientationButton":
                    {
                        buttonImageSwitch = new SwitchButtonImage(ImageOrientationButton, "ImageOrientationIndex");
                        break;
                    }
                case "InputFolderBrowseButton":
                    {
                        InputFolderTextBox.Text = new ItemSaveToConfig.SelectFolderSaveProperty(InputFolderTextBox.Text, "Select the input folder", "InputFolder").folderSelect;
                        break;
                    }
                case "OutputFolderBrowseButton":
                    {
                        OutputFolderTextBox.Text = new ItemSaveToConfig.SelectFolderSaveProperty(OutputFolderTextBox.Text, "Select the output folder", "OutputFolder").folderSelect;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        private void LoadControls(LoadInternalSettings Settings)
        {
            InputFolderTextBox.Text = InternalSettings.InputFolder;
            OutputFolderTextBox.Text = InternalSettings.OutputFolder;
            NumberOfZonesTextBox.Text = InternalSettings.NumberOfZones;
            FirstZoneWidthTextBox.Text = InternalSettings.FirstZoneWidth;
            LastZoneWidthTextBox.Text = InternalSettings.LastZoneWidth;
            ZoneAreaWidthTextBox.Text = InternalSettings.ZoneAreaWidth;
            ZoneAreaHeightTextBox.Text = InternalSettings.ZoneAreaHeight;
            ZoneWidthTextBox.Text = InternalSettings.ZoneWidth;
            TimerTextBox.Text = InternalSettings.Timer;
            ZoneWidthTextBox.Text = InternalSettings.ZoneWidth;
            ImageRotationButton.ChangeClickCountFromConfigFile(Int32.Parse(InternalSettings.ImageRotationIndex));
            ImageOrientationButton.ChangeClickCountFromConfigFile(Int32.Parse(InternalSettings.ImageOrientationIndex));
            //xmlRotateFront.ChangeClickCountFromConfigFile(internalSettings.XMLtoPPFRotateFrontIndex);
            var RotatePreview = new SwitchButtonImage(ImageRotationButton, "ImageRotationIndex");
            var OrientationPreview = new SwitchButtonImage(ImageOrientationButton, "ImageOrientationIndex");
        }
        private void TextBoxChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox TxtBx = sender as Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox;
            string TxtName = TxtBx.Name;
            switch (TxtName)
            {
                case "NumberOfZonesTextBox":
                    {
                        NumberOfZonesTextBox.Text = new ItemSaveToConfig.ChangeAndSaveTextBox(NumberOfZonesTextBox.Text, "NumberOfZones", false).TextToApply;
                        break;
                    }
                case "ZoneWidthTextBox":
                    {
                        ZoneWidthTextBox.Text = new ItemSaveToConfig.ChangeAndSaveTextBox(ZoneWidthTextBox.Text, "ZoneWidth", false).TextToApply;
                        break;
                    }
                case "FirstZoneWidthTextBox":
                    {
                        ZoneWidthTextBox.Text = new ItemSaveToConfig.ChangeAndSaveTextBox(FirstZoneWidthTextBox.Text, "FirstZoneWidth", false).TextToApply;
                        break;
                    }
                case "LastZoneWidthTextBox":
                    {
                        ZoneWidthTextBox.Text = new ItemSaveToConfig.ChangeAndSaveTextBox(LastZoneWidthTextBox.Text, "LastZoneWidth", false).TextToApply;
                        break;
                    }
            }


        }
        private void RadForm1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            new ItemSaveToConfig.SelectItemSaveProperty("Timer", TimerTextBox.Text.ToString());
            //WaitingTimer.Stop();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

FileProcessor Code:

```
    using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;
using DI_Plot_2018.IZData;

namespace DI_Plot_2018
{
    class FileProcessor : IDisposable
    {
        // Create an AutoResetEvent EventWaitHandle
        private EventWaitHandle eventWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        private readonly object locker = new object();
        private Thread worker;                
        public Queue<string> FilesQueue = new Queue<string>();
        private Queue<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> JobsQueue = new Queue<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>();
        private Dictionary<string, List<string>> FullJob = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        #region IDisposable Members
        public FileProcessor()
        {
            worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Work));
            worker.IsBackground = true;
        }
        public void FireProcessing(double counter)
        {
            int filesQueuedCounter = FilesQueue.Count;
            if (counter <= 0) //Timer is over, proceed with execution
            {
                lock(locker)
                {                    
                    while (filesQueuedCounter > 0)
                    {
                        string currFilename = FilesQueue.Dequeue(); //Dequeue filename
                        JobDetails CurrentJobInfo = new JobDetails(currFilename); //Get information about the job 
                        //Checking if dict already has the key - if it does, add the filename at the key position
                        if (FullJob.ContainsKey(CurrentJobInfo.JobNameWithoutColor))
                            FullJob[CurrentJobInfo.JobNameWithoutColor].Add(currFilename);
                        else //if it doesn't, add the new key and start the value (List<string>) with the current filename
                            FullJob.Add(CurrentJobInfo.JobNameWithoutColor, new List<string>() { currFilename });
                        filesQueuedCounter--;
                    }//End while loop - Dequeue all files
                    foreach (var item in FullJob) //Enqueue files in a jobs queue (KeyValuePair queue)
                    {
                        JobsQueue.Enqueue(item);
                    }
                    eventWaitHandle.Set();                    
                    worker.Start();
                }                                    

            }
        }
        public void EnqueueJob(string FileName, double counter)
        {            
            if(counter > 0)
            {
                lock(locker)
                {
                    FilesQueue.Enqueue(FileName);
                }                
            }             
        }
        private void Work()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> JobToRun = new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>();
                lock (locker)
                {
                    if(JobsQueue.Count > 0)
                    {
                        JobToRun = JobsQueue.Dequeue();
                        if (JobToRun.Key == null) return;
                    }
                    if(JobToRun.Key != null)
                    {
                        ProcessJob(JobToRun);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        eventWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void ProcessJob(KeyValuePair<string,List<string>> currJob)
        {
            string x = string.Empty;

        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Signal the FileProcessor to exit
            FilesQueue.Enqueue(null);
            JobsQueue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>("aa", new List<string>() { "aa"}));
            // Wait for the FileProcessor's thread to finish
            worker.Join();
            // Release any OS resources
            eventWaitHandle.Close();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more a code review question, there is another StackExchange site that will deal with this.